# Script Command without Junk Character

Tags: scripting

I'm Using Unix `script` command to record everything which is output to the terminal and place it in a log file. but when I see recorded file, it also include Junk Character.

So how to record terminal activity without Junk Character.

Output Example :
[image]

I have tried to convert file to dos using `todos`, `vim` and also tried with `dos2unix` but it skipping file `dos2unix: Skipping binary file`.

Comment: please recreate the screenshot with a terminal which is not transparent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if you'll be able to get rid of those easily. From the `script` man page:

> Certain interactive commands, such as vi(1), create garbage in the
>   typescript file.  Script works best with commands that do not
>   manipulate the screen, the results are meant to emulate a hardcopy
>   terminal.

The above output you're showing are the escape codes which produce the colored output in your terminal along with what looks to be someone hitting the backspace after making some corrections to typos.

#### using col

I did find this on SuperUser which makes use of the `col` command to cleanup the output:

```
$ col -bp typescript | less -R
```

If that doesn't work you can try this variant too:

```
$ col -bp < typescript
```

#### commandlinefu

I found this solution on [commandlinefu.com](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/2318/fix-a-typescript-file-created-by-the-script-program-to-remove-control-characters) which uses Perl and col together.

```
$ cat typescript | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' \
                 | col -b > typescript-processed
```

#### References

- [How to clean up output of linux 'script' command](https://superuser.com/questions/236930/how-to-clean-up-output-of-linux-script-command)
- [col man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/col)

Comment: Thanks, it's remove 99% junk character, but still remain one i.e `^G`

Comment: What if you run the file out through cat, `cat typescript`?

Comment: when I used `cat typescript`, It's Output OK, what I want, but when I redirect Output to another file, then junk character appear into that file..

Comment: @RahulPatil - how about the perl option?

Comment: have you worked on `Openstack` I just want some information on the same.

Comment: @RahulPatil - good. I haven't, but ask a question on the site if you have something specific. I've looked into it before and I use a lot of the same infrastructure that it offers.

Comment: I'm trying to clean the output of `script -ra` or even `script -r`.  This didn't work. Plain `script` with no options or arguments, produces a clean `typescript` file.