# Convert screen log to html

Tags: gnu-screen, ansi-term

I would like to log actions made in a terminal window, and convert the log to html on fly.

I already tried commands script/screen + [ansi2html](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ansi2html), but the result is not perfect: the escape sequences for line editing is not handled correctly, so in the resulting html I have a mixture for the old and the new version of the line.
So if the output of the terminal is like

```
$> echo Original text
Original text
$> echo Other
Other
```

The resulting html is

```
 $> echo Original text
 Original text
 $> echo Othernal text
 Other
```

Any idea, how to solve the issue?

Comment: Refer this link and remove junk char from script output http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86901/script-command-without-junk-character

Comment: @Rahul: the link you send is interesting, but still the result is not perfect, if I reedit a line.

Comment: Can you Update in Question what you have tried so far and what is not working... ?

Comment: @Rahul I tried the perl script ( `perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g'`), on a script log, where I have rewritten the line "echo Original text" to "echo Other". In the output, I saw "echo Othernal text"

Comment: Can you post sample file ? you can use http://paste.ubuntu.com/ for the same

Comment: See it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ka1i8ous6zrfpv/sample.zip)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your Perl script (which should be unnecessary) but `ansi2html` which is incomplete.

The logfile shows that something printed some text and then

- repeatedly added the escape sequence for clearing the remainder of the line `\E[K`
- alternately adding a backspace.

In `ansi2html`, the script finds escape sequences, and then ignores all but a few of those which it finds, i.e.,

[`self.ansi_codes_prog = re.compile('\033\\\[' '(\[\\d;\]*)' '(\[a-zA-z\])')`](https://github.com/ralphbean/ansi2html/blob/develop/ansi2html/converter.py#L235)

[`if command not in 'mMA':`](https://github.com/ralphbean/ansi2html/blob/develop/ansi2html/converter.py#L278)

Getting rid of the repeated stuff is simplest in a loop.  Here is an alternate script which works around the problems seen in `ansi2html` for your example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

while (<>) {
    my $save = "";
    while ( $save ne $_ ) {
        $save = $_;
        s/[^\010]\010\e\[K//;
    }
    $save = "";
    while ( $save ne $_ ) {
        $save = $_;
        s/[^\010]\010//;
    }
    s/\e\[\?[;0-9]*[\100-\176]//g;
    s/\e\][^\a]*\a//g;
    print;
}
```

and (calling that `filterit`), use it like this:

```
./filterit < 1.log | ansi2html >1.html
```