# How to convert a colored file to mail readable in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, files, sendmail

I have a file which was created by a script which will be colored when I open using `cat`. But when I tried to send that file as attachment, it is not showing properly. Like below it is showing.

```
^[[33m================================================================================^[[m
                            ^[[34m172.29.0.110^[[m
^[[33m================================================================================^[[m
Filesystem              Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos  109G   13G   91G  13% /
/dev/mapper/mpatha       1.6T  1.3T  277G  83% /var/lib/SQL
^[[33m================================================================================^[[m
                            ^[[34m172.29.8.110^[[m
^[[33m================================================================================^[[m
Filesystem              Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos  117G  9.1G  102G   9% /
/dev/mapper/mpatha       1.6T  1.4T  109G  93% /var/lib/SQL
^[[33m================================================================================^[[m
                            ^[[34m172.29.16.110^[[m
^[[33m================================================================================^[[m
Filesystem              Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos      117G   18G   94G  17% /
/dev/mapper/VG01-LV 1.5T  812G  590G  58% /var/lib/SQL
^[[33m================================================================================^[[m
                            ^[[34m172.29.26.110^[[m
^[[33m================================================================================^[[m
Filesystem              Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on
/dev/mapper/LogVol02  117G   22G   90G  20% /
/dev/mapper/mpathm    1.6T  1.1T  435G  71% /var/lib/SQL
```

The script(part of the script) that creates the file is ::

```
for IP in $(cat file.txt); do
    (echo -e  "\e[33m$LINE\e[m"
    echo -e "                            \e[34m$IP\e[m                                 "
    echo -e "\e[33m$LINE\e[m"
    echo -e "Filesystem\t\tSize\tUsed\tAvail\tUse%\tMounted\ton"
    ssh $SSH_ARG -q user@${IP} "df -Ph | egrep -iv 'filesystem|boot|tmpfs'") >> /disk_${DATE}_log
    echo -e "\e[33m$LINE\e[m"
    echo "Successful for $IP"
done

cat disk_${DATE}_log | mail -s "Disk space" mail@mail.com
```

I can remove those `echo`'s that creating colors, but I want to know is there any way I can send this file properly by mail or can I do something in mail command to solve this?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  This question is _not_ asking how to strip out or to not even send the control codes, as the questioner clearly states.  This question is asking how to generate non-`text/plain` mail messages with the `sendmail` and `echo` commands; or how to view the aforegiven bodypart in such a way that the escape sequences are processed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what's asked by

- converting the file with *ANSI color escapes* to HTML, and
- sending the resulting HTML file as an attachment.

The command-line **`mail`** (or **`mailx`**) program may not be very useful for this, but there are different versions (see for example *[Mailx send html message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24010230/mailx-send-html-message)*).  But without knowing what specific implementation of "mail" you are using, other (more predictable) tools work well.

Many mail clients (such as `mutt`) can be configured to display an HTML attachment using a suitable viewer.  See for example *[Reading HTML email with Mutt](https://debian-administration.org/article/75/Reading_HTML_email_with_Mutt)*.

For converting, there are a few scripts/programs, e.g., [more than one named "ansi2html"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ansi2html&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).  I commented on one in *[Convert screen log to html](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91821/convert-screen-log-to-html/306008#306008)*, which may work for you (see [link to script](http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/ansi2html.sh)).

For sending the attachment, keep in mind that you cannot simplify *pipe* the data to the mail client, and that the command-line parameters differ.  Some discussion focusing on `mutt` is given in *[How do I send a file as an email attachment using Linux command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17359/how-do-i-send-a-file-as-an-email-attachment-using-linux-command-line)*