# How Do I Unbuffer The Output Passed From an Interactive Command Into a Pipeline Ending With `tee`?

Tags: bash, osx, pipe, buffer, homebrew

I'm troubleshooting an interactive command and would like to:

- see output printed to my screen with its original coloration, unbuffered or line-buffered (instead of *block*-buffered,) as that command produces it
- <s>use something like `tee` to redirect this command's output to a file at the same time, preserving — that is, not garbling (such as by passing [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) through raw instead of processing them properly) — its coloration in this resulting log file.</s>  (I've realized that part of this preference probably isn't possible and thus replaced it with those that follow.)
- use `tee` or something like it to redirect this command's output to a file at the same time
- display output as colored by the command in question at run-time
- not pollute the resulting logs with [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) — that is, strip them from the output after displaying that on the terminal but *before* saving it to the log file.

Normally, `tee -a` does this for me with the output from the same kind of command I'm trying to log here like a charm, but *some* odd corner case I've hit in the pipeline ending in `tee` is disrupting this normal, sensible behavior, it seems.  I've done a *bit* of digging around to see if anybody's had a similar problem before and come up with a solution for it, but all the relevant material I've been able to dredge up is this:

- [How to make output of any shell command unbuffered? — Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465619/how-to-make-output-of-any-shell-command-unbuffered)
- [Preserve colors while piping to tee — SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/352697/preserve-colors-while-piping-to-tee)
- [Turn off buffering in pipe — Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)
- [Script Command without Junk Character — Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86901/script-command-without-junk-character)
- [Removing control chars (including console codes / colours) from script output — Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output)
- [format output from Unix “script” command: remove backspaces, linefeeds and deleted chars? — Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152339/format-output-from-unix-script-command-remove-backspaces-linefeeds-and-delet)
- [Realtime print statements with tee in interactive script — Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311873/realtime-print-statements-with-tee-in-interactive-script)

None of these resources, however, *quite* offer enough hints that I think I might be able to use them to cobble something along the lines of what I'm after together on my own nearly as quickly as I'd *like* — so I can finally pass the logs I need help generating on to somebody who can *glean* something from them, of course.
     I've *tried* a few different variations on the `unbuffer`- and `script`-based suggestions on offer in what I've perused already and was considering giving `stdbuf` some gos before I started writing this question up, but haven't gotten around to doing that last one just yet.  I'm using `/usr/bin/bash` on OS X v10.11.6 'El Capitan.'  The command I'm trying to troubleshoot is `HOMEBREW_BUILD_FROM_SOURCE=1 brew upgrade -vd --build-from-source mailutils`, where `brew` is [the Homebrew package manager](https://brew.sh/) and the version of Mailutils I'm trying to build from source and to which I'm trying to upgrade is v3.3 (I currently have v3.2,) but I *deeply* suspect that switching it out with an entirely *different* command that *also* produces block-buffered output when used as part of a pipeline (which, if I understand *correctly*, would be *any* shell command, as I've seen it mentioned that setting up a pipeline may incur block buffering in and of itself) would not solve my problem here.  What tool or tools might I be able to use to achieve the outcome I seek with respect to the logs I'm trying to capture here?

Comment: Note that the reason that I thought I'd post this question _here_ instead of, say, [Homebrew's Discourse board](https://discourse.brew.sh/), is that I bet that answers to it will be useful to anybody else who's _also_ trying to capture colored output from an interactive command in a file while still viewing it as it is produced at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [Process substitution](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/bashref.html#SEC32)<sup>1</sup> lets you transform a [`script`](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~gini/1901-07s/files/script.html) typescript as it's written.

You can use `script -q >(./dewtell >>outfile) brew args...` instead of `script -aq outfile brew args...` to write a log with escape sequences removed, where `./dewtell` is whatever command runs the script that removes them. On other systems than relatively recent versions of macOS or FreeBSD, the command will be slightly different, because different `script` implementations support different options. See below for full details.

### The Story So Far (including alternative solutions)

#### Your solution

Your `brew` command runs numerous other output-generating programs as subprocesses, such as `./configure` scripts and `make`, and you have found that piping `brew`'s output to `tee` with `brew args... 2>&1 | tee -a outfile` causes the output (of at least some of those subprocesses) to be buffered and not to appear on your terminal in real time.

[You found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402577/11938) that using `script`, by running `script -aq`, solved this problem by keeping [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) a terminal<sup>2</sup>, and that you can also pass `-k` if you want your own input logged *even in situations when it is not echoed to the terminal as you type it*. You found further that [dewtell's extended version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18979/11938) of [Gilles's Perl script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14707/11938) to [remove escape sequences from files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output) cleans up the the generated typescript effectively, transforming it into what you need.

The difference between Gilles's original script and dewtell's extended version is that, while they both remove escape sequences, including but not limited to those that specify color changes, dewtell's script also removes carriage return characters (`$'\r'`, represented as `^M` in `vim` and in the output of `cat -v`) as well as backspace characters (`$'\b'`, represented as `^H` in `vim` and in the output of `cat -v`) and whatever characters, if any, that they appear to have erased.

#### Problems with some Perl implementations

You reported that the script needs a "relatively recent" Perl interpreter. But it doesn't call for any newer features with [`use`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html) or otherwise appear to rely on them, and a friend of mine who runs macOS 10.11.6 El Capitan has verified that it works with the system-provided perl 5.8.12, so I don't know why (or if) you needed a newer perl. **I expect *most* people can just use the perl they have.**

But the script **did fail** on Mac OS X 10.4.11 Tiger (PPC) with the system-provided perl 5.8.6, which incorrectly believes (at least on my system) that `m` is not in the character class `[@-~]`, even with `LC_COLLATE=C` or `LC_ALL=C` and even though the system-provided `grep`, `sed`, `python`, and `ruby` do not have this problem. This caused pieces of color-specifying escape sequences to remain in the output, as the sequences failed to match `(?:\e\[|\x9b) [ -?]* [@-~]` and matched the later alternative `\e.` instead. With [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/), I installed perl 5.27.5, 5.8.9, and even 5.6.2 on that system; none had the problem.

If one does need or want to run the script with a Perl interpreter installed elsewhere than `/usr/bin/perl`, then one can change the [hashbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line at the top to the correct path; or one can change it to `/usr/bin/env perl` if the desired `perl` executable appears first in the path, i.e., if it would run if one typed `perl` and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>; or one can invoke the interpreter explicitly with the script's filename as its first argument, e.g., `/usr/local/bin/perl dewtell` instead of `./dewtell`.

#### Ways to keep or replace the original typescript

Some users who need to remove escape sequences from a typescript will want to keep the old unprocessed typescript too. If such a user wishes to process a typescript called `dirty.log` and write the output to `clean.log`, they would run `./dewtell dirty.log > clean.log`, if necessary replacing `./dewtell` with whatever other command runs [dewtell's script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18979/11938) (or some other script they wish to use).

To modify the typescript "in place" instead, one can pass `-i` to `perl`, running `perl -i.orig dewtell typescript` where *`typescript`* is the typescript generated by `script`, `.orig` is any suffix to be used for the backup file, and `dewtell` is the Perl script. Or one may instead run `perl -i dewtell typescript`, which discards the original because no backup suffix is supplied. These methods don't work with all Perl scripts but they work with this one because it uses `<>` to read input, and [`<>` in Perl respects `-i`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-i*[_extension_]).

You used `sponge` to write the changes back to the original typescript. This is also a good and reliable method, though it requires that [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) be installed.

### Preventing Escape Sequences From Ever Being Logged

The remaining question is how to write a log that has escape sequences removed in the first place. As [you say](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402577/11938):

> [T]here may further be a way to string this all together into a single pipeline, but I haven't been able to figure that out as of this writing; additional comments or answers showing how...

#### Use process substitution instead of a pipeline.

The problem is that `script` on most (all?) systems does not have an option to support those transformations. Since `script` writes to a file whose name you either specify or defaults to `typescript`--not to standard output--piping from `script` would not affect what is written to the typescript.

Placing the `script` command on the right side of the pipe operator (`|`) to pipe *to* it is not a good idea either. In your case this is specifically because output from `brew` or its subprocesses was buffered when its standard output was a pipe, so it didn't appear when you needed to see it.

Even if that problem were solved, I don't know of any reasonable way to use a [*pipeline*](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/bashref.html#SEC17)<sup>1</sup> together with `script` to accomplish this task.

**But it can be done with process substitution.**<sup>3</sup> In [process substitution](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/bashref.html#SEC32)<sup>1</sup> (also [explained here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)), you write `<(command...)` or `>(command...)`. The shell creates a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) and uses it as standard output or input, respectively, for a [subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell) in which *`command...`* is run. The text `<(command...)` or `>(command...)` is replaced with the filename of the named pipe--that's the *substitution*--so you can pass it as an argument to a program or use it as the target of a redirection.

- Use `<(command...)` to run *`command...`* like **its output** is the contents of a file you'll **read from**.<sup>4</sup>
- Use `>(command...)` to run *`command...`* like **its input** is the contents of a file you'll **write to**.<sup>4</sup>

Not all systems support named pipes, but most do. Not all shells support process substitution, but Bash does, so long as it's running on a system that is capable of supporting it, your build of Bash hasn't omitted support for it, and POSIX mode is turned off in the shell. In Bash you *usually* have access to process substitution, especially if you're using any remotely recent operating system. Even on my Mac OS X 10.4.11 Tiger (PPC) system where `"$BASH_VERSION"` is `2.05b.0(1)-release`, process substitution works just fine.

#### Here's how to do that while using `script`'s syntax on a recent macOS system.

This should work on your macOS 10.11 El Capitan system--and, going by [that manpage](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/script.1.html), any macOS system **at least as far back as macOS 10.9 Mavericks** and possibly earlier:

```bash
script -q >(./dewtell >>clean.log) brew args...
```

That logs everything written to the terminal, including your own input *if it is echoed back to you*, i.e., if it appears in the terminal, which it usually does. If you want your own input logged *even if it doesn't appear*, bearing in mind that the situation where this occurs is often that you are entering a password, then as you mentioned in [your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402577/11938), add the `-k` option:

```bash
script -kq >(./dewtell >>clean.log) brew args...
```

In either case, replace `./dewtell` with whatever command runs [dewtell's script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18979/11938) or any other program or script you want to use to filter the output, *`clean.log`* with name of the file you want to write the typescript to with escape sequences omitted, and `brew args...`<sup>5</sup> with the command you are running and its arguments.

### Overwriting or Appending to the Log

If you want to overwrite *`clean.log`* instead of appending to it then use `>clean.log` instead of `>>clean.log`. The actual file is being written by the command that is run via process substitution, so the `>` or `>>` redirection operator appears inside `>(` `)`.

Don't attempt to use `>>(` instead of `>(`, which is a syntax error as well as meaningless because the `>` in `>(` for process substitution does not mean redirection.

Don't pass `-a` to  `script` with the intention that it would prevent your log file from being overwritten in this situation, because this would simply open *the named pipe* in append mode--which has the same effect as opening it for a normal write--and then either overwrite or append *`clean.log`*, still depending on whether `>clean.log` or `>>clean.log` is used in the subshell.

Similarly, don't use `>&` or `&>` or add `2>&1` inside `>(` `)` (or anywhere), because if `./dewtell` generates any errors or warnings, you would want to see those rather than having them written to *`clean.log`*. The `script` command automatically includes text from standard error in its typescript; you don't need to do anything special to achieve this.

### On Other Operating Systems

As [your answer](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/script.1.html) says:

> [S]ome versions of the `script` command have a different syntax; the one given is for OS X/macOS, so adjust as necessary.

#### GNU/Linux

Most GNU/Linux systems use the `script` implementation provided by [util-linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Util-linux). If you want to cause it to run a specific command rather than starting a shell, you must use the `-c` option and pass the entire command as *a single command-line argument* to `script`, which you can achieve by enclosing it in quotes. This is different from the version of `script` on recent macOS systems like yours, which allows you to pass the command naturally as multiple arguments placed after the output filename (with no option like `-c`).

So **on Debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, CentOS, and most other GNU/Linux systems**, you could use this command (if it had a `brew` command<sup>6</sup>, or replacing it with whatever command you want to run and log transformed output):

```bash
script >(./dewtell >>clean.log) -qc 'brew args...'
```

As with `script` on your system, on GNU/Linux remove `-q` if you want `script` to include more messages about how logging has begun and ended. Even with the `-q` option, this version of `script` does still include one line at the top saying when it started running, though it does not show *you* that line and it does not write or show anything about when it *stopped* running.

There is no `-k` option. Only text that appears in the terminal is recorded.<sup>7</sup>

#### FreeBSD

The `script` command in macOS originated in FreeBSD. All versions support `-a` to append instead of overwriting (though, as noted above, this does not help you append when you are writing through a named pipe using process substitution). `-a` was the only option up to and including [FreeBSD 2.2.5](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=script&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%202.2.5-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html). The `-q` option was [added in FreeBSD 2.2.6](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=script&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%202.2.6-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html). The `-k` option was [added in FreeBSD 2.2.7](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=script&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%202.2.7-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html).

Up [through FreeBSD 2.2.5](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=script&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%202.2.5-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), the `script` command did not allow a specific command to be given, but instead always ran the user's shell, given by the `SHELL` environment variable, with `/bin/sh` as a fallback if the variable is unset. [Starting in FreeBSD 2.2.6](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=script&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%202.2.6-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html), a specific command could be given on the command line to `script` which it would run instead of a shell.

Thus later versions of FreeBSD, including those commonly encountered today, are similar to newer macOS systems such as yours in the way the `script` command may be invoked. Likewise, older versions of FreeBSD are similar to older versions of macOS (see below).

Note that `perl` is not part of FreeBSD's base system in any recent release, and `bash` never has been. Both may be readily installed using packages (such as with `pkg install perl5 bash bash-completion`) or ports. The system-provided `/bin/sh` in FreeBSD does not support process substitution.

#### Older Versions of macOS, and any other system with a less versatile `script`

I tested on Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger where `script` accepts *only* the `-a` option. It does not accept `-q` or `-k`. It includes only keystrokes shown in the terminal in its typescript<sup>7</sup>, as with the util-linux version on GNU/Linux systems.

At least until I can find a reliable source of documentation for `script` in every version of macOS (to my knowledge, only [the 10.9 Mavericks manpages](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/) are readily available online), **I recommend macOS users run `man script`** to check what syntax their `script` command accepts, how it behaves by default, and what options it supports. You would want to use these commands on an old version of macOS like mine:

```bash
script >(./dewtell >>clean.log)
brew args...
exit
```

This also applies to `script` **on any other OS where it doesn't support many options**, or on OSes where other options are supported but you prefer not to use them. This method of using `script` to start a shell, running whatever command or commands in the shell that you need logged, and then exiting the shell, is the traditional way.

#### The ugly hack of pretending your command is your shell

If you really must use `script` to run a single command rather than a new instance of your shell, there is an ugly hack that you can sometimes use: you can fool it into thinking the command you want to run is actually your shell with `SHELL=your-command script outfile`. You should think twice before doing this, though, because if *`your-command`* itself actually consults the `SHELL` environment variable to check what actual shell you use, <s>hilarity</s> unfortunate behavior would ensue.

Furthermore, that will not readily work for a command consisting of multiple words--that is, a command to which you are passing one or more arguments. If you wrote `SHELL='brew args...'` before `script` on the same line, that would succeed at passing `brew args...` into `script`'s environment as the value of `SHELL`, but that entire string would be used as the name of the command, rather than just the first word, and no arguments would be passed to the command, rather than all the other words being passed.

You could work around this by writing a shell script, called `run-brew` or whatever you want to call it, that runs `brew` with *`args...`*, and then passing that as the value of the `SHELL` environment variable. After you've made the `run-brew` shell script, running it via the `script` command could look like this:

```bash
SHELL=run-brew script >(./dewtell >>clean.log)
```

For the reasons given above, I recommend against using the method of assigning your command name to `SHELL`, unless the action you are performing is unimportant or you are sure it will not involve the use of `SHELL`. Since Homebrew performs numerous, quite complicated actions, I suggest against actually running a `run-brew` script like this. (There's nothing wrong with putting your long, complicated `brew` command in a `run-brew` script, only with using `SHELL=run-brew` to make `script` run it.)

I did find this method a bit useful when testing the techniques shown above with a simple program in place of `brew args...`, however.

### Testing and Demonstrating the Technique

You may find it useful to try out some of these methods on a command less complicated than your long `brew` command. I know I did.

#### The demo program / test input generator, and the testing method used

I made this simple interactive Perl script that writes to standard error, prompts the user on standard output for their name, reads it from standard input, then writes a greeting to standard output with the user's name in color:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Term::ANSIColor;

print STDERR $0, ": warning: this program is boring\n";
print "What's your name?  ";
chomp(my $name = <STDIN>);
printf "Hello, %s!\n", colored($name, 'cyan');
```

I called it `colorhi` and put it in the same directory as [dewtell's script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18979/11938), which I called `dewtell`.

In my own testing I replaced `#!/usr/bin/perl` with `#!/usr/bin/env perl` in both scripts.<sup>8</sup> I tested in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the system-provided perl 5.22.1 and versions 5.6.2 and 5.8.9 provided by `perlbrew`; FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE-p3 with the `pkg`-provided perl 5.24.3 and versions 5.6.2, 5.8.9, and 5.27.5 provided by `perlbrew`; and Mac OS X 10.4.11 Tiger with the system-provided perl 5.8.6 and versions 5.6.2, 5.8.9, and 5.27.5 provided by `perlbrew`.

I repeated the tests described below with each of those perl versions, first testing the system-provided<sup>9</sup> version, then using `perlbrew use` to temporarily cause each `perlbrew`-provided `perl` binary to appear first in `$PATH` (e.g., to test perl 5.6.2, I ran `perlbrew use 5.6.2`, then the commands shown below for the system on which I was testing).

A friend tested it in macOS 10.11.6 El Capitan, with the original hashbang lines, causing the system-provided perl 5.18.2 to be used, and not testing any other interpreters. That test employed the same commands I ran while testing on FreeBSD.

**All those tests succeeded except with the system-provided perl in Mac OS X 10.4.11 Tiger**, which failed due to what appears to be a strange bug involving character classes in regular expressions, as I described earlier in detail, and as shown below in an example.

#### On Ubuntu

While in the directory that contained the scripts, I ran these commands on the Ubuntu system to produce a typescript with escape sequences and any backspace characters I might type:

```bash
printf 'Whatever header you want...\n\n' >dirty.log
script dirty.log -aqc ./colorhi
```

I typed `Eliah`, then behaved as though I had thought better of it, erasing it with backspaces and typing `Bob from accounting` instead. Then I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and was greeted in color. Then I ran these commands to *separately* produce a typescript without escape sequences and without any signs of my real name, interacting with it in exactly the same way (including typing and erasing `Eliah`):

```bash
printf 'Whatever header you want...\n\n' >clean.log
script >(./dewtell >>clean.log) -qc ./colorhi
```

`vim` displays control characters symbolically like `cat -v` and offers the advantage of brightened or colored text. This is what the buffer shown by `view dirty.log` looked like, but with the representations of control characters italicized so they stand out here:

```
Whatever header you want...

Script started on Thu 09 Nov 2017 07:17:19 AM EST
./colorhi: warning: this program is boring^M
What's your name?  Eliah^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^H^H ^HBob from accounting^M
Hello, ^[[36mBob from accounting^[[0m!^M
```

And this is what the buffer looked like for `view clean.log`:

```
Whatever header you want...

Script started on Thu 09 Nov 2017 07:18:31 AM EST
./colorhi: warning: this program is boring
What's your name?  Bob from accounting
Hello, Bob from accounting!
```

Results were the same with each interpreter tested, except of course for the timestamp.

#### On FreeBSD (and macOS 10.11.6 El Capitan)

I carried out the test the same way on FreeBSD as on Ubuntu, except that I used these commands to produce `dirty.log`:

```bash
printf 'Whatever header you want...\n\n' >dirty.log
script -aq dirty.log ./colorhi
```

And I used these commands to produce `clean.log`:

```bash
printf 'Whatever header you want...\n\n' >clean.log
script -q >(./dewtell >>clean.log) ./colorhi
```

**Those are the same commands my friend ran to test this on macOS 10.11**, and although the input issued was slightly different from my `Eliah`/`Bob from accounting` input, a name was still typed, erased with backspaces, and replaced by another name. The output was thus similar except for the names and number of backspaces.

With all four of the Perl implementations tested on FreeBSD and the one (system-provided) implementation on macOS 10.11, both `dirty.log` and `clean.log` showed the expected output. Comparing the FreeBSD results with the Ubuntu results, the difference was the absence of any timestamps, due to `-q`. All escape sequences and carriage returns were successfully removed in `clean.log`, as were all backspaces and characters whose erasure the backspaces indicated.

#### On Mac OS X 10.4.11 Tiger

I carried out the test the same way on my old Tiger system as on Ubuntu and FreeBSD, except that I used these commands to produce `dirty.log`:

```bash
printf 'Whatever header you want...\n\n' >dirty.log
SHELL=colorhi script -a dirty.log
```

And I used these commands to produce `clean.log`:

```bash
printf 'Whatever header you want...\n\n' >clean.log
SHELL=colorhi script >(./dewtell >>clean.log)
```

Since this system's `script` command doesn't support `-q`, results included both *(a)* a `Script started` line appended after the header and *(b)* a newline followed by a `Script done` line appended at the very end of each typescript. Both those lines contained timestamps. Besides that, the results were the same as on Ubuntu and FreeBSD, except that **the escape sequences to switch to and from cyan text were not fully removed with the system-provided `perl`**. The relevant line from `dirty.log` always appeared this way in `vim`, as expected:

```
Hello, ^[[36mBob from accounting^[[0m!^M
```

With the system-provided perl 5.8.6, this was the corresponding line in `clean.log`, showing `6m` and `0m`, which should have been removed, left over:

```
Hello, 6mBob from accounting0m!
```

With each of the `perlbrew`-installed perls, all escape sequences were fully and correctly removed, and that line in `clean.log` looked like this, just as it did with all Perl interpreters I ran on Ubuntu and FreeBSD:

```
Hello, Bob from accounting!
```

### Notes

<sup>1</sup> [That manual](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/bashref.html) is for Bash 2. Many Bash users are on major version 4 and will prefer to read about [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), [pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines), and other topics in [the current Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/). Current versions of macOS ship with Bash 3.

<sup>2</sup> [Standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) is almost always unbuffered, regardless of what type of file or device it is. There is no rule that programs cannot buffer writes to file descriptor 2, but there is a strong tradition not to do so, based in the need to actually see error and warning messages when they occur--and also the need to see them *at all*, even if the program terminates abnormally without ever properly closing or otherwise flushing its open file descriptors. It would usually be a bug for a program to buffer writes to standard error by default.

<sup>3</sup> Process substitution uses a *named pipe*, also called a *FIFO*, which achieves the same general goal as the pipe operator `|` in shells, but is more versatile. However, even though this *is a pipe*, I consider that it is not *a pipeline*, which I take to refer to the specific syntactic construct and corresponding behavior of a shell.

<sup>4</sup> If you consider a named pipe to be a file, which [you should](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file), then this is literally what is happening.

<sup>5</sup> Although `"$COMMAND"` appears in [your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402577/11938) and passes an entire command as a single argument to `script` (because [double quotes](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/bashref.html#SEC11) suppress [word splitting](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/bashref.html#SEC33)), you were able to pass the command to `script` [as multiple arguments](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=40956696#40956696).

<sup>6</sup> Such as with [Linuxbrew](http://linuxbrew.sh/), which I should acknowledge [you introduced me to](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/26?m=40927879#40927879).

<sup>7</sup> However, I recommend that anyone who relies on this behavior to keep sensitive data secret test the behavior of their `script` command, and maybe even inspect generated typescripts to ensure no data that must be protected are present. To be extra safe, use an editor that shows characters that would ordinarily be hidden on screen, or use `cat -v`.

<sup>8</sup> The versions with `#!/usr/bin/perl`, including the `colorhi` implementation shown, should work and do the right thing on most systems. I used `#!/usr/bin/env perl` in my own testing. But my friend who has the same OS that you (the original poster) are running used `#!/usr/bin/perl`. This achieved the goal of checking, with minimal complication or potential for doubt, that the system-provided perl would work.

<sup>9</sup> On FreeBSD there is no system-provided perl in the strictest sense. I tested the version installed via `pkg` first.

Comment: TL;DR has never been so needed

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow Perhaps, but `script -q >(./dewtell >>outfile) brew args...` is prominently shown at the top. The first heading and the short paragraph that follow it summarize the most important and widely applicable parts of the answer. Do you think it would actually be useful to slap a "TL;DR" on that? ...Or perhaps you just mean that it's too long and you didn't read it. If so, that's definitely fine -- I divided it into marked sections so that people can benefit without reading all or even most of it. Readers who just want to apply the technique can skip to the section for their OS.

Comment: @EliahKagan:  The only reason I recommended that users make sure they have a 'relatively recent' version of Perl to run the script was just that I thought that it's always better to be safe than sorry, for I hadn't put in the time to check whether said script actually _depended_ on any features introduced in newer Perl versions.  Plus, I wouldn't want others to be using an old version of Perl in other settings where having the latest security patches would matter, so I decided to kill multiple birds with one stone, so to speak.

Comment: @EliahKagan:  Also, it would be handy if the in-text footnote references had links to their respective footnotes (as well as links _back_ — those are useful when lots of scrolling is involved, regardless of content.)  Perhaps I might go ahead and fix that for you…?

Comment: @EliahKagan:  With respect to troubleshooting the Perl problems you _did_ encounter, you could also have gotten around them by obtaining other versions of Perl whose behavior you wanted to check from [Tigerbrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew) instead of from Perlbrew.

Comment: @EliahKagan:  Just so you know, I switched the Perl script's shebang line to use `env` as well.

Comment: @RandomDSdevel I used Perlbrew to support the other systems I wanted to test: GNU/Linux, which is very popular, and FreeBSD, which is somewhat similar to macOS. As for the footnotes, you definitely have my blessing to make links between them and the text that references them, if you find a practical way of doing so. But I don't think you can. As [codewaggle says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140524), [SE only allows `href` and `title` on `a`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909). See also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230737) and [that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5017).

Comment: @EliahKagan w. r. t. Perlbrew:  Of course.  Just wanted to let you know about another option for one of the systems you tested on.

Comment: @EliahKagan w. r. t. footnotes:  Oh, pity; now _that's_ somewhat annoying… — well, not by _much_, but you get the point, anyway.  Well, at _least_ that makes me feel a bit less depressed about accidentally navigating away from the edit screen and losing my work in progress to try to fix this answer's navigation issues…

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
package require Tcl 8.5
if {[llength $argv] == 0} {
    puts stderr "Usage: $argv0 logfile command \[cmd-args ..]"
    exit 1
}
set ::argv [lassign $::argv thelogfile]
log_file $thelogfile
spawn -noecho {*}$argv
interact
```

Everything should be appended (that's the default for `log_file` documented in `expect(1)`) to the given log file, while `interact` lets you fiddle around with the spawned command. Example usage:

```
$ rm out
$ ./yointeract out sh
$ echo hi
hi
$ printf "\033[10Ghi\n"
         hi
$ exit
$ xxd out
00000000: 2420 6563 686f 2068 690d 0a68 690d 0a24  $ echo hi..hi..$
00000010: 2070 7269 6e74 6620 225c 3033 335b 3130   printf "\033[10
00000020: 4768 695c 6e22 0d0a 1b5b 3130 4768 690d  Ghi\n"...[10Ghi.
00000030: 0a24 2065 7869 740d 0a                   .$ exit..
$
```

P.S. this is more or less what the `autoexpect(1)` program does, which also ships with or at least near to `expect(1)`

Comment: Looks like I have `autoexpect` on my system since I installed `expect` through Homebrew when I tried using it before (specifically, its `unbuffer` command,) so I'll use that.  Thanks for pointing it out to me, @thrig!

Comment: After looking at `autoexpect`, I don't see how it could help with the task at hand here; it seems like the plain old Expect script you gave me should do the trick, as I'm not trying to _automate_ my interaction with the command I'm troubleshooting, just wanting to log its output.

Comment: I stand corrected:  the script provided by this answer passes ANSI escape codes through, not their effects, so it doesn't serve my needs as expressed in my OP.

Comment: What format would you propose for storing the effects of a terminal emulator in a file? What would display that format?

Comment: I've been discussing this with @EliahKagan in chat, and, after digging through some old logs I've taken that _don't_ cause the infrastructure that creates them to hiccup in the way that caused me to ask this question in the _first_ place, I realized that I've only seen color in the output at run-time, not in the resulting logs.  I've amended my question to match, but my normal method still doesn't work for this one corner case, so my OP still stands, though updated.  I suppose one could use `asciinema` or run a `script` typescript through some text editor that recognizes formatting.

Answer (score 1):

After multiple sessions in chat with @EliahKagan, here's what he helped me to come up with:

First, gather the following prerequisites:

- A command to run whose standard output and error you want to log, obviously; in what follows, I'll refer to this as `"$COMMAND"`.
- A file to which you'll append logs (this way, you can leave a comment at its top to say what generated those logs; at least, that's how I tend to document things.)  In what follows, I'll refer to this as `"$LOG_FILE"`.
- An installation of a relatively recent version of [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) (*not* Perl *6*, which is *not* compatible with previous mainline releases of the language) if you don't have one already.
- An executable copy of the Perl script given by @dewtell in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18979/86927) to [this other Unix & Linux Stack Exchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14684/86927).  In what follows, I will refer to this as `"$RM_ANSI_ESC_SEQS_SCRIPT"`.
- An installation of [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) (for `sponge`.)

Modify your `"$PATH"` so that your shell (I'm using `bash`, but others might be perfectly suitable for the procedure outlined here with little to no alteration to these instructions) can find Perl and moreutils.  `script`, the other command referenced in this answer, should already be available on your system, at least if you're running a relatively recent version of OS X/macOS on your machine like I am.  If it isn't or you want to install a newer version of it from another source for any reason, please go and fix that or do so now.
     Next, run the following commands in sequence, one after the other:

```
script -aq "$LOG_FILE" "$COMMAND" # Add the `k` option, either separately or as part of the group of short options already given to this command, if you want to log user input as well.  
"$RM_ANSI_ESC_SEQS_SCRIPT" "$LOG_FILE" | sponge "$LOG_FILE"
```

Note also that some versions of the `script` command have a different syntax; [the one given is for OS X/macOS](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/script.1.html), so adjust as necessary.  Aside from that, that's all there is to it.  I should add, however, that there may further be a way to string this all together into a single pipeline, but I haven't been able to figure that out as of this writing; additional comments or answers showing how one might do that are also welcome.

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402577/86927) has now been replaced by [a better one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403598/86927).

Comment: I'm pleased to hear you like my answer! However, I recommend against deleting this one, as I expect it will also help people. (I'm guessing you *are* planning to keep it, but I figured I'd comment just in case, since you said "replaced.") This answer describes some things that mine does not, as well as showing your solution in a different way that may benefit some people, and it has the benefit of brevity. I also reference this answer to support several statements I make in mine. So my answer would not be as good as it currently is, if this one were removed.

Comment: @EliahKagan:  Yeah, I wasn't planning on deleting it.  I should probably have said 'superseded,' as that might fit the situation a tad better since that wouldn't necessarily imply deletion, only archival.